# entity framework not return refrence table data after insert new record to child table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6. There is two table like `parent and child` with foreign key on `parentid`. I a`dded one new record in child table and savechanges()` done. When i execute this query `var childdata= _context.child.Where(p => p.childid == childid).FirstOrDefault();` then it return child table properly but when i use `childdata.parent` then it shows null. As there is foreign key between tables it should return parent data when we get child table data.

There is three projects. They are `Repository, webapplication and webservice.`. and calling is cross repositiory. SO when i call from webservice it works fine rturn parent data but in webapplication it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Include()` method to include parent:

```
childdata= _context.child.Include("parent").Where(p => p.childid == childid).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: but it should return without using `include`. For other tables it;s working